# Measure theory for $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have some questions about measure theory.

$u,v,w \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$

We suppose $u,v,w$ are bounded and $|u(x)|\leq |v(x)|+|w(x)|$, $|u(x)-u(y)|\leq |v(x)-v(y)|+|w(x)-w(y)|$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $K_{n}:=\{|v|^{2}+|w|^{2}>\frac{1}{n}\}$ then $1_{K_{n}}u\to u$, $1_{K_{n}}v \to v$ and $1_{K_{n}}w \to w$, as $n\to \infty$

Claim1: $m(K_{n})<\infty$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ( $m$ is Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}}))$ )

Claim2: We can assume $m\left(\{u \neq 0 \} \cup\{v \neq 0 \} \cup \{w \neq 0\} \right)< \infty$

---

Proof of Claim1:

Since $v,w \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, $\infty>\int_{\mathbb{R}}(|v|^{2}+|w|^{2})dm\geq\int_{K_{n}}(|v|^{2}+|w|^{2})dm>\frac{1}{n}m(K_{n})$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I want to explain Claim2.  How should I think about that?

Add: My purpose is proving the following inequality:

$(\int_{\mathbb{R}}F|u|\cdot|u|dm)^{1/2}\leq (\int_{\mathbb{R}}F|v|\cdot|v|dm)^{1/2}+(\int_{\mathbb{R}}F|w|\cdot|w|dm)^{1/2}$

where $F:L^{2}(\mathbb{R})\to L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is bounded linear operator on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Claim2 requires a purpose for which you may make the stated assumptions. What is this purpose?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My purpose is proving the above inequality

Comment: Ah. Then the point is most likely to use Claim1. If you can show the inequality whenever you replace $u$, $v$, $w$ by $1_{K_n}u$, $1_{K_n}v$,  $1_{K_n}w$, then you can use a convergence theorem to extend the inequality to the general case.

Comment: (On a side note, unless you know that $F$ is positive definite, you could have trouble with some of your square roots.)